# why vue.js computed get undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just wanna use Vue computed, but I get `undefined(styleObj.width)`, and it seems that the computed function was not called (didn't log 'computed'). And when I changed data while the computed function was still not be called and the data `(styleObj.width)` was still `undefined`.

The code is simple and I hope you know what I'm talking about.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
      #app {
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" :style="styleObj"></div>

    <script>
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          num: 100,
          styleObj: {
            width: this.calcWidth, // always be undefined even num has changed
          },
        },
        computed: {
          calcWidth() {
            console.log('computed') // never log 'computed' which means the
            // calcWidth not be called
            return this.num + 'px'
          },
        },
      })

      setTimeout(() => {
        vm.num = 200
      }, 2000)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why the `calcWidth` function never be called? I think it will be called twice, at the beginning and in 2 sec, but it never be called. Why?
2. Why the `styleObj.width` has always been undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems.

The way it's written currently, the `this` in `width:this.calcWidth` will not be referring to the correct object. It needs to be within a function to get the scoping correct. That is easily fixed by changing `data` to a function.

The next problem is that computed properties are not available within the `data` function. The order is roughly:

1. Provide/inject
2. Props
3. Data
4. Computed

Things lower down that list can use things higher up the list, not the other way around.

Instead you can make the whole style object a computed property:

```js
computed: {
  styleObj () {
    return {
      width: this.num + 'px'
    }
  }
}
```

or if you prefer to retain `calcWidth`:

```js
computed: {
  styleObj () {
    return {
      width: this.calcWidth
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: very clear.but I still don't know why the calcWidth function not be called?because we can't use compued properties in data so it won't be called?@skirtle

Comment: @Archsx 1. Your `this` reference is incorrect so when you wrote `this.calcWidth` it wasn't even accessing the right object. 2. Even if you solved that it wouldn't work because computed properties aren't wired up until after `data`. 3. The timer has no effect on `calcWidth` as computed properties are computed lazily so unless something asks for `calcWidth` it won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `computed property` in `data`, because `data` evaluates before the `computed properties` did.

You can use a `watcher` to achieve the intended result:

```
watch: {
  num(val) {
    this.styleObj.width = val + 'px'
  }
}
```

If `num` changes the `watcher` get triggered.
See the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) on that.

Edit:
You can use the argument `immediate` to trigger directly:

```
watch: {
  num: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(val) {
       this.styleObj.width = val + 'px'
    }
  }
}
```